# Which vuetify file do I download to include in my project

Tags: vuetify.js

I want to add vuetify to my project, but it can only be added by downloading files.

I have downloaded vuetify.min.css and vuetify.min.js

What other files do I need to download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Vue CLI then you can just add it like so:
`vue add vuetify`

The doc: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#vue-cli-install

It also contains other installation methods if that one doesn't suit you, if you want to install it manually I think there are only these two (as seen in the code working with the CDNs), but maybe you'll want to use de Material Design Icons then you need to download that as well.